# How to enable Core-Rules in SQL-Fluff and solve TomlDecodeError?

Tags: continuous-integration, toml, pyproject.toml, sqlfluff

I want to enable only the [core group of rules](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/rules.html#core-rules) in SQL-Fluff.
So I added this line to my pyproject.toml file:

```
[tool.sqlfluff]
rules = "core"
```

This results in the following error message:

```
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\toml\decoder.py", line 134, in load
    return loads(ffile.read(), _dict, decoder)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\toml\decoder.py", line 478, in loads
    raise TomlDecodeError("What? " + group +
toml.decoder.TomlDecodeError: What? rules already exists?{'rules': 'core', 'core': {'dialect': 'tsql', 'exclude_rules': 'L016,L057,L029'}} (line 24 column 1 char 483)
```

What does this error mean and how do i solve it to achieve my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself. I will post it here since i still don't find it intuitive and others may have the same problem.

So, if you only want to use the core set of SQL-Fluff rules, add the following to your pyproject.toml

```
[tool.sqlfluff.core]
rules = "core"
```